# Xslt 1.0 Specific Substring

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a string like this and i need to get specific substring between specific |'s. Like between first | and second | (5000935). I use the code below for that but i need easier way for further substrings.

102237315|5000935|771803||139566.66|0|139566.66|139566.66|||string|Y||P150007170|46193808

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after( . ,'|'),'|')"/></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use XSLT 2.0 you can tokenize on each pipe

your XML:

```
<td><string>102237315|5000935|771803||139566.66|0|139566.66|139566.66|||string|Y||P150007170|46193808</string></td>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:variable name="token" select="tokenize(td/string, '\|')" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$token[3]"/>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Outputs:

```
<output>771803</output>
```

> note the | delimiter will need to be escaped with a \ as seen above.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 is in the title.  [xslt-1.0] is the sole tag.

Comment: Thanks I'm looking for something like this but I must use XSLT 1.0